# How to get three.js LineSegments to only render visible lines

Tags: three.js

I’m trying to get Three.js to render only the `FrontSide` outlines of geometries. What I want to achieve is a look as close as possible to this:

[image]

With `BoxGeomtry` I came close to what I want, but using `LineSegments` on a `CylinderGeometry` gives vertical lines, which makes sense. Can you think of a way I can draw only the "visible" outlines?

[image: Cylinder with LineSegments here]

Here is what I tried so far:

```
let coloredMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
  color: 0xFFD033,
  polygonOffset: true,
  polygonOffsetFactor: 1,
  polygonOffsetUnits: 1
});

let brick = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, coloredMaterial);

let edges = new THREE.EdgesGeometry(brick.geometry);
var outline = new THREE.LineSegments(edges, new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({
  color: 0x1B3740,
  linewidth: 1.5
}));

let knobGeometry = new THREE.CylinderGeometry(7, 7, 7, 20);
let knob = new THREE.Mesh(knobGeometry, coloredMaterial);

let knobOutline = new THREE.LineSegments(
  new THREE.EdgesGeometry(knob.geometry),
  new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({
    color: 0x1B3740,
    linewidth: 1.5
  })
);
```

Comment: This is a potentially really tricky problem.. just a heads up.

One partial approach is to make a .clone() of your mesh and use meshBasicMaterial. Control drawing order via object.renderOrder to make the basicmaterial mesh render first.. which will write it into the depth buffer, then draw your wireframe second... this will remove back faces.. but wont help with the vertical lines on the cylinder sides.

Comment: Another approach is to do the lines as a post process. Render your object.. but then run a fullscreen shader with the depth buffer / or normal buffer as an input and for each fragment, look at neighboring fragments to see if the normal/depth deviates by some threshhold value, and only draw pixels if true. This is more robust/general, but harder to implement.

Comment: If you want to ask questions about threejs, I help mod a slack channel for threejs discussion. https://join.slack.com/t/threejs/shared_invite/enQtMzYxMzczODM2OTgxLTQ1YmY4YTQxOTFjNDAzYmQ4NjU2YzRhNzliY2RiNDEyYjU2MjhhODgyYWQ5Y2MyZTU3MWNkOGVmOGRhOTQzYTk

Comment: @Mary (1) Try `new THREE.EdgesGeometry( geometry, angle_in_degees );` or (2) study how `conditionalLineVertShader` works in `LDrawLoader` in https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_loader_ldraw.html`.

Comment: Thank you all! Looks like a couple of starting points. I already expected it to be a more complex problem than it seems to be. Postprocessing seems to heavy to implement. I will check it out tomorrow. 

Comment: @WestLangley thanks for pointing out on thresholdAngle. I didn‘t notice that option on EdgesGeometry – looks promising.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This answer is based on @WestLangley's suggestion on the comments, specifically the model used by `LDrawLoader` on conditional lines.

---

### Control points model

The idea behind conditional lines is to use control points to determine which lines should be drawn.

If the two control points lie on the same side of the clip plane, created by extrapolating the line to infinity, then the line is drawn. Else it is discarded.

[image: https://www.ldraw.org/uploads/images/Articles/opline.gif]

Let's consider 2 lines **(E,B)** and **(F,C)**:

For **(E,B)**, let's use **(A)** and **(C)** as controls points. We can clearly see that both control points are on the same side of the plane created by **(E,B)**. Therefore, this line is drawn.

For **(F,C)**, let's use **(B)** and **(D)** as controls points. Now, both control points lie on different sides of the plane. So, this line is discarded.

---

As the implementation of this model can be quite lengthy, I've setup a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/atujr54z/) that can be used as a reference. It's not quite perfect, but I believe it should be helpful enough.

[image]

We can't use `CylinderBufferGeometry` as a base for the edges geometry, because it uses an indexed buffer geometry. Since the control points are determined by each of the lines, and not the vertices, we don't use indices.

For edges that aren't conditional, we can use the same point for both controls, e.g top and bottom circles.

An important thing to notice is that we can't determine, with this model, if a line would be occluded by geometry (what you described as frontSide). So, I used the actual knobs to occlude the back lines.

```js
var conditionalLineVertShader = /* glsl */ `

            attribute vec3 control0;
            attribute vec3 control1;
            attribute vec3 direction;

            varying float discardFlag;

            #include <common>
            #include <color_pars_vertex>
            #include <fog_pars_vertex>
            #include <logdepthbuf_pars_vertex>
            #include <clipping_planes_pars_vertex>

            void main() {

            #include <color_vertex>

            vec4 mvPosition = modelViewMatrix * vec4( position, 1.0 );
            gl_Position = projectionMatrix * mvPosition;

            // Transform the line segment ends and control points into camera clip space
            vec4 c0 = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4( control0, 1.0 );
            vec4 c1 = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4( control1, 1.0 );
            vec4 p0 = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4( position, 1.0 );
            vec4 p1 = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4( position + direction, 1.0 );

            c0.xy /= c0.w;
            c1.xy /= c1.w;
            p0.xy /= p0.w;
            p1.xy /= p1.w;

            // Get the direction of the segment and an orthogonal vector
            vec2 dir = p1.xy - p0.xy;
            vec2 norm = vec2( -dir.y, dir.x );

            // Get control point directions from the line
            vec2 c0dir = c0.xy - p1.xy;
            vec2 c1dir = c1.xy - p1.xy;

            // If the vectors to the controls points are pointed in different directions away
            // from the line segment then the line should not be drawn.
            float d0 = dot( normalize( norm ), normalize( c0dir ) );
            float d1 = dot( normalize( norm ), normalize( c1dir ) );

            discardFlag = float( sign( d0 ) != sign( d1 ) );

            #include <logdepthbuf_vertex>
            #include <clipping_planes_vertex>
            #include <fog_vertex>

            }
            `;

var conditionalLineFragShader = /* glsl */ `

            uniform vec3 diffuse;
            varying float discardFlag;

            #include <common>
            #include <color_pars_fragment>
            #include <fog_pars_fragment>
            #include <logdepthbuf_pars_fragment>
            #include <clipping_planes_pars_fragment>

            void main() {

            if ( discardFlag > 0.5 ) discard;

            #include <clipping_planes_fragment>

            vec3 outgoingLight = vec3( 0.0 );
            vec4 diffuseColor = vec4( diffuse, 1.0 );

            #include <logdepthbuf_fragment>
            #include <color_fragment>

            outgoingLight = diffuseColor.rgb; // simple shader

            gl_FragColor = vec4( outgoingLight, diffuseColor.a );

            #include <premultiplied_alpha_fragment>
            #include <tonemapping_fragment>
            #include <encodings_fragment>
            #include <fog_fragment>

            }
            `;

var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
  antialias: true
});
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

var scene = new THREE.Scene();
scene.background = new THREE.Color(0xffffff);
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);
var controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);

camera.position.set(10, 13, 10);
controls.target.set(0, 0, 0);


// cube

var cubeGeometry = new THREE.BoxBufferGeometry(10, 5, 10);
var cubeMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
  color: 0xFFD033,
  polygonOffset: true,
  polygonOffsetFactor: 1,
  polygonOffsetUnits: 1
});
var cube = new THREE.Mesh(cubeGeometry, cubeMaterial);
scene.add(cube);

var edgesGeometry = new THREE.EdgesGeometry(cubeGeometry);
var edgesCube = new THREE.LineSegments(edgesGeometry, new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({
  color: 0x1B3740,
  linewidth: 1.5
}));
edgesCube.position.y += 0.6;
scene.add(edgesCube);


// knob

var knobGeometry = new THREE.CylinderGeometry(1.4, 1.4, 0.8, 30);
var knob = new THREE.Mesh(knobGeometry, cubeMaterial);
knob.position.set(-2.5, 2.9, -2.5);
scene.add(knob);

var knob = new THREE.Mesh(knobGeometry, cubeMaterial);
knob.position.set(2.5, 2.9, 2.5);
scene.add(knob);

var knob = new THREE.Mesh(knobGeometry, cubeMaterial);
knob.position.set(-2.5, 2.9, 2.5);
scene.add(knob);

var knob = new THREE.Mesh(knobGeometry, cubeMaterial);
knob.position.set(2.5, 2.9, -2.5);
scene.add(knob);


// knob edges

var edgesMaterial = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
  vertexShader: conditionalLineVertShader,
  fragmentShader: conditionalLineFragShader,
  uniforms: {
    diffuse: {
      value: new THREE.Color(0x1B3740)
    }
  },
  linewidth: 1.5
});

var edgesKnob = createCylinderEdges(1.4, 0.8, 30);
edgesKnob.position.set(-2.5, 2.9 + 0.6, -2.5);
scene.add(edgesKnob);

var edgesKnob = createCylinderEdges(1.4, 0.8, 30);
edgesKnob.position.set(2.5, 2.9 + 0.6, 2.5);
scene.add(edgesKnob);

var edgesKnob = createCylinderEdges(1.4, 0.8, 30);
edgesKnob.position.set(-2.5, 2.9 + 0.6, 2.5);
scene.add(edgesKnob);

var edgesKnob = createCylinderEdges(1.4, 0.8, 30);
edgesKnob.position.set(2.5, 2.9 + 0.6, -2.5);
scene.add(edgesKnob);


window.addEventListener('resize', onResize);


function animate() {

  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  controls.update();
  renderer.render(scene, camera);

};


function createCylinderEdges(radius, height, segments) {

  var geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry();

  var v0 = new THREE.Vector3();
  var v1 = new THREE.Vector3();

  var vertices = [];
  var control0 = [];
  var control1 = [];
  var directions = [];

  // top / bottom circles

  for (var v = 0; v <= 1; v++) {

    for (var x = 0; x < segments; x++) {

      var th = (x / segments) * Math.PI * 2;
      var c0 = ((x - 1) / segments) * Math.PI * 2;
      var c1 = ((x + 1) / segments) * Math.PI * 2;

      var sinTheta = Math.sin(th);
      var cosTheta = Math.cos(th);

      v0.x = radius * sinTheta;
      v0.y = -v * height + height / 2;
      v0.z = radius * cosTheta;

      sinTheta = Math.sin(c1);
      cosTheta = Math.cos(c1);

      v1.x = radius * sinTheta;
      v1.y = -v * height + height / 2;
      v1.z = radius * cosTheta;

      vertices.push(v0.x, v0.y, v0.z);
      vertices.push(v1.x, v1.y, v1.z);

      control0.push(v0.x, v0.y, v0.z);
      control0.push(v0.x, v0.y, v0.z);

      control1.push(v0.x, v0.y, v0.z);
      control1.push(v0.x, v0.y, v0.z);

      directions.push(v1.x - v0.x, v1.y - v0.y, v1.z - v0.z);
      directions.push(v1.x - v0.x, v1.y - v0.y, v1.z - v0.z);

    }


  }

  // vertical edges

  for (var x = 0; x < segments; x++) {

    var th = (x / segments) * Math.PI * 2;
    var c0 = ((x - 1) / segments) * Math.PI * 2;
    var c1 = ((x + 1) / segments) * Math.PI * 2;

    var sinTheta = Math.sin(th);
    var cosTheta = Math.cos(th);

    v0.x = radius * sinTheta;
    v0.y = height / 2;
    v0.z = radius * cosTheta;

    v1.x = radius * sinTheta;
    v1.y = -height + height / 2;
    v1.z = radius * cosTheta;

    vertices.push(v0.x, v0.y, v0.z);
    vertices.push(v1.x, v1.y, v1.z);

    directions.push(v1.x - v0.x, v1.y - v0.y, v1.z - v0.z);
    directions.push(v1.x - v0.x, v1.y - v0.y, v1.z - v0.z);

    var sinTheta = Math.sin(c0);
    var cosTheta = Math.cos(c0);

    v0.x = radius * sinTheta;
    v0.y = height / 2;
    v0.z = radius * cosTheta;

    control0.push(v0.x, v0.y, v0.z);
    control0.push(v0.x, v0.y, v0.z);

    var sinTheta = Math.sin(c1);
    var cosTheta = Math.cos(c1);

    v0.x = radius * sinTheta;
    v0.y = height / 2;
    v0.z = radius * cosTheta;

    control1.push(v0.x, v0.y, v0.z);
    control1.push(v0.x, v0.y, v0.z);

  }


  geometry.setAttribute('position', new THREE.Float32BufferAttribute(vertices, 3));
  geometry.setAttribute('control0', new THREE.Float32BufferAttribute(control0, 3, false));
  geometry.setAttribute('control1', new THREE.Float32BufferAttribute(control1, 3, false));
  geometry.setAttribute('direction', new THREE.Float32BufferAttribute(directions, 3, false));

  return new THREE.LineSegments(geometry, edgesMaterial);

}

function onResize() {

  var w = window.innerWidth;
  var h = window.innerHeight;

  camera.aspect = w / h;
  camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

  renderer.setSize(w, h);

}

animate();
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  position: fixed;
}

canvas {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.122.0/build/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.122.0/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Just awesome, thank you very much for your detailed explanation and the fiddle!

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you could probably copy the approach used in the [toon shader example](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/webgl_materials_variations_toon.html)

Not only does it use `MeshToonMaterial` for the solid color, but also uses `OutlineEffect` found in `./jsm/effects/OutlineEffect.js`. You can see [in the source code](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/webgl_materials_variations_toon.html), the relevant points are:

```
import { OutlineEffect } from './jsm/effects/OutlineEffect.js';

// Pass renderer to effect constructor
renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
effect = new OutlineEffect( renderer );

// In the render loop:
effect.render( scene, camera );
```

Comment: I think OP is looking for edges outline instead of silhouette outline.

Comment: Yeah, now that I look at WestLangley's comment above I think his example is probably better suited.

Comment: @Marquizzo thanks anyway – outline would still be better than nothing. ;)