# Add edge line to 3D object with Three.js

Tags: three.js

I am trying to add the edge lines to the 3D object with Three.js. Here is the object loaded:

[image]

Here is the code I used to draw the edges:

```
// geometry is the object loaded from remote server
const edgeGeometry = new EdgesGeometry( geometry );
const edgeMaterial = new LineBasicMaterial( { color: 0x333333, linewidth: 0.5 } );
const edgeWireframe = new LineSegments( edgeGeometry, edgeMaterial );
scene.add(edgeWireframe );
```

The result is like this:

[image]

This the goal I am trying to achieve:

[image]

Only the edges have the lines. The question is: How can I draw the edge lines without these lines on the curve surfaces? Thank you for your time.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56795062/how-to-get-three-js-linesegments-to-only-render-visible-lines/

Comment: Hi, @ScieCode. Thanks for your reply. But my case is that the object was loaded from remote server. There is no way I can control how the 3D object is constructed. The only thing I receive is the `geometry` object passed by the loader.

Comment: You would need to 1) detect the edges that you've deemed as edges, and 2) Create a "halo" effect to show the outlines of the curved sides of the cylinders. **For your specific shape**, you could detect edges by comparing face normals of adjacent faces. If the angle between the normals is PI/2, then the shared side of the faces is an "edge."